# Combining data in two ILists containing missing values and duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am working with an API and a data Client that returns two ILists: "devices" and "manufacturers".
There are ~100 manufacturers and ~2000 devices.

manufacturer.code is a two or three character code

manufacturer.value is the full name of the manufacturer

device.manufacturerCode = manufacturer.code
(device also has 20 other properties)

What I want to do is replace the value of device.manufacturerCode with the full name of the manufacturer.
e.g.

before: device.manufacturerCode = "AC"

after: device.manufacturerCode = "Acme Products"

This is my attempt:

```
IList<deviceDTO>device = await DataClient.MakeApiHttpRequestAsync(.......);
IList<manufacturerDTO>manufacturer = await DataClient.MakeApiHttpRequestAsync(.......);

for (int i = 0; i < device.Count(); i++)
{
     device[i].ManufacturerCode = (from x in manufacturer
                                     where x.Code == device[i].ManufacturerCode
                                     select x.Value).ToList().First();
}
```

There are a few problems:

1) There are duplicates in manufacturers (but it doesn't matter which I choose as long as I choose one)

2) Some device.manufacureCode's are missing from manufacturers, this causes the above code to error. I want it to keep the two characters if there is no equivalent full name.

3) My solution (even if it worked) looks very inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those numbers I wouldn't stress out about the performance. But that aside; I'd suggest (since the name can be a duplicate and any will do) you create a dictionary of code / names and compare your device list (only those you know) to that dictionary.
Somewhere along the lines of this:

```
IList<deviceDTO> devices = await DataClient.MakeApiHttpRequestAsync(.......);
IList<manufacturerDTO> manufacturer = await DataClient.MakeApiHttpRequestAsync(.......);
var manufacturerList = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(var code in manufacturer.Select(x => x.code).Distinct())
{
    manufacturerList.Add(code,manufacturer.First(c => c.code == code).value; 
}

foreach(var device in devices.Where(d => manufacturerList.Keys.Contains(d.manufacturerCode)))
{
    device.manufacturerCode = manufacturerList[device.manufacturerCode];
}
```

Above is untested and uncompiled...

**Edit / addition**

For your error #2 - that is because you do a First on a list that could perhaps not contain your key (besides the fact you do the comparison each iteration) - it should be (in this case) a FirstOrDefault.. like this:

```
device[i].ManufacturerCode = (from x in manufacturer
                                     where x.Code == device[i].ManufacturerCode
                                     select x.Value).ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? device[i].ManufacturerCode;
```

Comment: I added your code and it all worked perfectly. the manufacturer code has been replaced with the manufacturer name. Duplicates and missing values are dealt with.